# Ubuntu 14.10 | I can't install Software

Tags: software-installation, software-center, dpkg, 14.10, gdebi

I can't install software after I installed Ubuntu 14.10 19 days ago.
If I want to install Skype I get (in German):

```
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
skype:i386 ist schon die neueste Version.
0 aktualisiert, 0 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 0 nicht aktualisiert.
1 nicht vollständig installiert oder entfernt.
Nach dieser Operation werden 0 B Plattenplatz zusätzlich benutzt.
Möchten Sie fortfahren? [J/n] j
icedtea-netx:amd64 (1.5.1-1ubuntu1) wird eingerichtet ...
update-alternatives: Warnung: Neuinstallation der Alternative /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/itweb-settings ist erzwungen, weil Linkgruppe itweb-settings defekt ist
update-alternatives: Warnung: /usr/share/man/man1/itweb-settings.1.gz wird nicht durch einen Link ersetzt
update-alternatives: Warnung: Neuinstallation der Alternative /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/itweb-settings ist erzwungen, weil Linkgruppe itweb-settings defekt ist
update-alternatives: Warnung: /usr/share/man/man1/itweb-settings.1.gz wird nicht durch einen Link ersetzt
update-alternatives: Fehler: Alternativen-Pfad /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/javaws existiert nicht
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes icedtea-netx:amd64 (--configure):
 Unterprozess installiertes post-installation-Skript gab den Fehlerwert 2 zurück
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
 icedtea-netx:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Looks like `skype` is installed already, but there seems to be an issue with the configuration of `icedtea-netx`. Please try to run Skype and on success [edit] your question to focus on the aforementioned issue. By the way, you can force English messages for any (well-behaving) command by pre-pending `LC_MESSAGES=C`, e. g. `LC_MESSAGES=C apt-get install -f`.

Answer (score 0):

It is because, the required unistall package found in the status file of dpkg directory. You can overcome the error as below.

```
#cd /var/lib/dpkg/ 
#status status.orig
# vim status
```

Search for a block something like that:

> Package: icedtea-netx:amd64
>
> ```
> ..
>
> ..
>
> Package: another_package_name
> ```

Here, you have to delete only icedtea-netx:amd64 block. This means starting with Package: icedtea-netx:amd64 and till the other package block. After deleting the block try to remove it again it will works.